# Imageview to show different image depending on Int

Tags: android, random, imageview

I have a random number generator and I need to display different image,
depending on different Int values.

For example when randomNumber is let's say 1, I need to show specific text and image
and when number is 10 another specific text and image etc..

Can I even do that with ImageView, I do not know where to start?

```
    package com.example.drinktivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonback); // Here the R.id.button1 is the button from you design
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View arg0) {
Intent i = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
}
});

ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
int random = bundle.getInt("Value");
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
if (random==1) {
    text.setText("");
}
if (random==2) {
    text.setText("");
}
if (random==3) {
    text.setText("");
}
if (random==4) {
    text.setText("");
}
if (random==5) {
    text.setText("");
}
if (random==6) {
    text.setText("");
}
if (random==7) {
    text.setText("");
}
if (random==8) {
    text.setText("");
}
if (random==9) {
    text.setText("");
}
if (random==10) {
    text.setText("");
}


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

    }
```

Comment: Please add some of your code..

Comment: Please tell your Random Number limit .??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[] i = {R.drawable.drawable1, R.drawable.drawable2, R.drawable.drawable2,      R.drawable.drawable4, R.drawable.drawable5,};
Random rand = new Random();
int  n = rand.nextInt(5);
imageView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(i[n]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a drawable array

```
  public static final int[] im_smiley_drawable_smile_old = {
                    R.drawable.im_smiley_happy, R.drawable.im_smiley_sad,
                    R.drawable.im_smiley_winking,
                    R.drawable.im_smiley_tongue_sticking_out,
                    R.drawable.im_smiley_surprised, R.drawable.im_smiley_kissing,
                    R.drawable.im_smiley_yelling, R.drawable.im_smiley_cool}
```

send ramdom numbers to this array you will get random images

Answer (score 0):

consider your int value as int random
and your random no consists of numbers 1 to 5.
then you can do this.

```
if(random==1){

imageview.setImageBitmap(yourbitmap);

//here imageview is your imageview. and then bitmap you want when the number generated is 1.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible, but there are a lot of ways of doing this. I think the main approach that you'd want to go for is generating a random number, and choosing an image from your resources based on that number. You can retrieve resources like this:

```
context.getResources().getIdentifier(i.getIcon(), "drawable", context.getPackageName())
```